# Widget editing returns JSON response error

Tags: widgets, json

I am trying to modify the sidebar widgets under **Appearance -> Widgets**, but whatever I do (just change one option, or remove a widget, etc.), as soon as I press the **Update** button, on the bottom left it says `There was an error. The response is not a valid JSON response.`

Upon inspecting the Network tab of the browser DevTools, the request is showing up as `v1?_local=user` and the request URL is `https://host/wp-json/batch/v1?_locale=user` with a method of `OPTIONS`. This request returns a status code 200, but there is no response data - unsure if this could be the issue or not.

What I tried so far (after each point I tried editing the widgets again):

- Updated WordPress to 5.9
- Updated all plugins
- Disabled all plugins
- Switched to a different theme
- Saved changes on the permalinks
- Used a different `.htaccess` suggested by a different website
- Checked the Site Health, it does not report any issues with the REST API

Everything else seems to work just fine, I can create/edit posts, pages, etc., but the widget editing keeps failing.

What else can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, no answer for you, but just to let you know you're not alone!! I'm currently having this issue for the first time on a new site I'm working on. Can't find a cause. The only thing I can think of is that this site is on a Windoze server rather than the Linux I'm used to! Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using IIS, check under "Handler Mappings" > "PHP_via_FastCGI" (or similar) > "Request Restrictions" > "Verbs" that "All verbs" is handled.

For me only "GET, HEAD, POST" was enabled and not OPTIONS.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I am using IIS and this fixed the problem perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The release of WordPress 5.8 removed the classic widgets editor in favor of the Gutenberg widget block editor to control your website widget areas.

**References**:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/block-based-widgets-editor-in-wordpress-5-8/

https://wordpress.org/news/2021/07/tatum/

**Old View of Widgets Dashboard**
[image]

**New View of Widgets Dashboard**
[image]

To fix the issue add following code in the functions.php file.

**File location**: /var/www/html/yoursite/wp-includes/functions.php

```
function example_theme_support() {
    remove_theme_support( 'widgets-block-editor' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'example_theme_support' );
```

Then after reload the widgets dashboard, you will see the old dashboard view and will be able to edit the widgets.

OR

You may transform the existing widget as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I hope these 2 solutions may help you.

**Note**: Remember to undo the changes done in the functions.php file.